# sort div on the basis of multiple data in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I am trying to implement best match functionality. Basically I am working on a assignment and I am not good at jQuery or JS. The functionality is like user will use search functionality to search property and the search result will be shown, there is a drop-down on top of searched results which have sorting options like sort by distance, by best match etc.. I already have implemented functionality of other sorting options, just best match is remaining. I am not getting how to approach this problem because for implementing best match I have to match all fields of each record displayed and sorting the results as per that. The main question is how to compare multiple fields of each record using jQuery.

Following is the format of displayed result:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="ptype">property type</div>
    <div id="ttype">sale</div>
    <div id="price">$20000</div>
    <div id="distance">24 Miles</div>
</div>
```

There would be multiple divs for different properties. Now I want to sort these results as per best match comparing each given fields like price, distance etc..

Pleas guide me how to approach this problem.

Comment: you should use `class` instead of `id` for ptype, ttype, price and distance. id is a unique identifier, there must not be several elements with the same id.

Comment: I'm thinking you are going to have to loop through each container and give each one a priority based on it's data and your search terms then sort them by priority.